# What should an BibTeX entry for a Stack Exchange post look like?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, best-practices

On (some?) science SE sites, we can get BibTeX code for citing posts. This is what this can look like:

```
@MISC{30073,
    TITLE = {Cutting equal sticks from different sticks},
    AUTHOR = {Erel Segal-Halevi (http://cs.stackexchange.com/users/1342/erel-segal-halevi)},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {Computer Science Stack Exchange},
    NOTE = {URL:http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30073 (version: 2015-02-16)},
    EPRINT = {http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30073},
    URL = {http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30073}
}
```

I think that this is weird; there's lots of redundant URLs and having the profile URL in the author field is likely to skrew with all kinds of sorting and citation routines. (`\authorcite`, oh dear!)

If you were to propose updating their BibTeX output to SE Oversight, what would you change in the status quo resp. my proposal, and why?
To be clear, I'm asking for the (La)TeX perspective here, not the SE perspective.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29428/discussion-on-question-by-raphael-what-should-an-bibtex-entry-for-a-stack-exchan).

Answer (score 4):

I would stick with Bibtex setting (bibltex style citation could and should be added as an additional style, like the amsref they have there).

@misc is the correct type of entry, that fits unpublished or online items.

The most important issue, in my eyes, is to have all the data in the record. It is usually harmless to have extra data, so I'm not so frightened of the URL/EPRINT redundancy. I am missing the year field (which in my eyes should be the year when the question was posted); month may be optional.

One thing that bothers me is the author. Having "user18324" or "themonkeybeater" as an author, doesn't seem right. But maybe there's no other way around it. Adding a link to the author profile is a nice idea.

So I'd go with

```
@misc{CS:30073,
    title = {Cutting equal sticks from different sticks},
    author = {Erel Segal-Halevi},
    authorurl = {http://cs.stackexchange.com/users/1342/},
    howpublished = {Computer Science Stack Exchange},
    year= {2014},
    note ={[Online:] \url{http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30073}},
    url = {http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30073},
    urldate = {2014-11-26}
}
```

---

a bit unrelated: what if you wish to cite the entire thread, rather than the specific question / specific answers? In this case, I would cite the same way as above, but removing the author.

Comment: Ad unrelated: if that should happen, why not cite all contributions independently?

Comment: Having BibTeX and Biblatex as separate options is a nice thought.

Comment: Reg unrelated: seems over-redundant, especially if there are, say, 3+ posts. I see this as citing a single web-page, and would like it to appear as a single citation.

Comment: Then you can probably just cite the website using "normal" code. This feature as I understand it is specifically designed to give attribution for individual posts.

Comment: @Raphael I don't know what "normal code" is. Anyways it is always simpler (and less prone to errors) if you start with the .bib provided to you, and make changes as needed.

Comment: I meant cite it how you would cite any website.

Comment: (+1) But I would add `month` and `day` for BibTeX. I wonder if there is a way in Biblatex of telling it to skip the `note` for this entry. Then you could avoid the redundancy.

Comment: @cfr You can certainly tell Biblatex to skip *all* notes, maybe only for the used entry type. I don't know that you can get it to skip *exactly* these notes, which is why I'd prefer to remove the redundancy. It seems impossible if you want to support both "idiomatic" BibTeX and Biblatex, however. (?)

Comment: Anyway, given the license needs we can not "hide" `authorurl`; it has to be displayed, so for BibTeX we have to integrate it into a standard field. Also, `urldate` is usually not supported (afaik). (This is going to be messy when it's done.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have created for the same post after browsing the documentation of [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
@online{cs.SE:30073,
  title = {Cutting equal sticks from different sticks},
  author = {Erel Segal-Halevi},
  nameaddon = {\url{http://cs.stackexchange.com/users/1342/}},
  howpublished = {Computer Science Stack Exchange},
  url = {http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30073},
  urldate = {2014-11-26},
  date = {2014-09-17}
}
```

In particular, note that

- the key is changed to be unique across SE sites (and more descriptive),
- every piece of information goes into an appropriate value,
- there is no redundant information, and
- posting and access date are both kept.

This renders to (using `biblatex` (with `biber` or `bibtex`) and `alphabetic` style):

[image]

I find the result quite pleasing; `nameaddon` is missing and would have to be added to the style if necessary, e.g. like so (for `biblatex`, due to [@moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe)):

```
\renewbibmacro{author}{% 
  \printnames{author}% 
  \setunit{\addspace}% 
  \printfield{nameaddon}% 
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{nameaddon}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
```

This may break styff your chose style does in arbitrarily nasty ways, so use at your own risk. You [*have* to show the author URL](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), though, so some change to the style and/or exported entry may be needed; this is a proof-of-concept.

For compatibility with older tools, one may want to add (redundant) `year` and `month` fields. Some styles (e.g. `plainnat`) support `url`, others (e.g. `alpha`) do not. Find an [MWE here](https://gist.github.com/reitzig/7991f77df96e0ef6671f) for playing around with.

Comment: I would feel more comfortable if you left out the `\renewbibmacro{author}` or explained more explicitly the problems it might cause (which are potentially huge: it will totally wreck `authoryear`-like styles, and it will have adverse effects on some of the options (`dashed`, `useauthor`) of other styles).

Comment: @moewe I mention it because the CC-by-SA 3.0 license requires attribution, which [in this case means](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) "Show the author names for every question and answer" and "Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site". It's important that the bib exports enables users to fulfill the requirements. I think that between my disclaimer and your comment (thanks for reposting is here!) it's clear that adapting the style has to be done carefully on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thank you. Though I don't think it is fair to suggest that the `biblatex` styles do nasty things. Even the default `\newbibmacro*{author}` in `biblatex.def` is more complicated than the code we have here and would be broken by the addition above.